# C# serialize JSON without property name

Tags: c#, json, serialization

maybe this was asked somewhere before, but I don't know how to search for my problem.
I'm using a WebAPI to verify licenses. From this API I get the return JSON string in follwing format.

```
string json = "[{"status":"error","status_code":"e002","message":"Invalid licence key"}]"
```

This is my serializer

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
{
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ActivationResponseWooSl));
                ActivationResponseWooSl ar = (ActivationResponseWooSl)js.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Now my questions is, how must the "ActivationResponseWooSl" class look like so that the serializer can convert it?

Any help is highly appreciated!

For now it looks like that (what's not workiing):

```
[DataContract]
public class ActivationResponseWooSl
{
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "status_code")]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

However when I serialize my json string, all properties are "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is correct. Your JSON is an array of object.

Try

```
DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ActivationResponseWooSl[]));
var arr = (ActivationResponseWooSl[])js.ReadObject(ms);
```

Comment: That was fast and the perfect solution! Thank you so much for your quick support :)

Comment: @AndreasReitberger Glad to help you :)