# Unable to deserialise JSON with list inside a list

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-deserialization

I have a JSON with data coming from an API

```
{"S":"Success","Result":{"Data":[[2251,2570205,"05-Sep-19 09:53 AM","--","Rs. 0","Cash","Amount Paid : 0"],[2248,3817456,"01-Sep-19 08:53 AM","--","Rs. 168.00","NC","Reason : NC"],[2247,2997168,"01-Sep-19 08:49 AM","16","Rs. 660.00","Card","Amount Paid : 660, Type : Visa"],[2245,6410400,"01-Sep-19 08:46 AM","16","Rs. 726.00","Card","Amount Paid : 726, Type : Visa"]],"Headers":["S.No.","Order Id","Date","Table No","Amount","Mode of Payment","More Info"],"Footer":["Total","4","","","Rs. 1,386.00","",""]}}
```

I need to convert this into C# object to be able to bind to the UI. Below is the C# Code

Code to deserialise object:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericJSONResponse<ReportRootObject>>(response);
```

I am getting the response inside the `response` object.

Objects:

```
public class ReportRootObject
    {
        public string S { get; set; }
        public ReportMasterDetailsData ReportMasterDetailsData { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ReportMasterDetailsData
    {
        public List<List<ReportMasterDetails>> Data { get; set; }
        public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
        public List<string> Footer { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class ReportMasterDetails
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string TableNumber { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public string ModeOfPayment { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
    }
```

WHen trying to access the fields using `jsonResult.Result.ReportMasterDetailsData.Data;`
I am getting a null reference exception at 'ReportMasterDetailsData'

WHat am I missing ??

Comment: try this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportRootObject>`

Comment: @Nkosi kindly elaborate ? using ``` json2csharp.com``` I get ```public class Result
{
    public List<List<object>> Data { get; set; }
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
    public List<string> Footer { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string S { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}```

Comment: @mtkachenko thats not the problem here.. ```GenericJSONResponse``` is just a Generic object

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: jsonResult.ReportRootObject.ReportMasterDetailsData.Data; or some cast...

Comment: @Nkosi not sure what you mean..

Comment: @st_stefanov casting is not the issue, ReportMasterDetailsData is itself null

Comment: That is null because that should be named `Result`

Comment: No @gpro Naming convention is fine.. please check the code in the question (not the one posted in comments)

Comment: @PranjalVatsa why do you think that problem not in `GenericJSONResponse`? Did you try my option?

Comment: @PranjalVatsa the jsonconverter matches the json keys to c# property names. it will never find the Result if that is named `ReportMasterDetailsData`. Since you did not set up any json attributes for guidance for the converter this will be the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Let's see your JSON result as formatted json:

```
{
  "S":"Success",
  "Result":
   {
    "Data":
     [
        [2251,2570205,"05-Sep-19 09:53 AM","--","Rs. 0","Cash","Amount Paid : 0"],
        [2248,3817456,"01-Sep-19 08:53 AM","--","Rs. 168.00","NC","Reason : NC"],
        [2247,2997168,"01-Sep-19 08:49 AM","16","Rs. 660.00","Card","Amount Paid : 660, Type : Visa"],
        [2245,6410400,"01-Sep-19 08:46 AM","16","Rs. 726.00","Card","Amount Paid : 726, Type : Visa"]
     ],
     "Headers":["S.No.","Order Id","Date","Table No","Amount","Mode of Payment","More Info"],
     "Footer":["Total","4","","","Rs. 1,386.00","",""]
   }
 }
```

Now let's look at your classes. `jsonResult.Result.ReportMasterDetailsData.Data`  will return null because in your JSON response property called `Result` not `ReportMasterDetailsData`, so rename `ReportMasterDetailsData` property to `Result`. If you don't want to change the name of property you can add  `[JsonProperty("Result")]` in your property

Type of  `Data` property of `ReportMasterDetailsData` class is `List<List<ReportMasterDetails>>`, but in JSON response this collection is coming without property name. You can change `List<List<ReportMasterDetails>>` to `List<List<string>>` and then somehow convert it to `ReportMasterDetails` class. Or you can deserialize it without using the property name. Look at [How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088941/how-to-deserialize-a-child-object-with-dynamic-numeric-key-names) and [C# serialize JSON without property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228506/c-sharp-serialize-json-without-property-name). I hope this can help you

Comment: That does not answer the question .. why must the property be called Result? DId you check my code in the question ??

Comment: @PranjalVatsa OK, if you don't want to change the name you can add [JsonProperty("Result")] in your property

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create model from json string and use `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` to do the rest of the job. Here is the code snippet i tried.

```
    public class Result
    {
        public List<List<object>> Data { get; set; }
        public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
        public List<string> Footer { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReportRootObject
    {
        public string S { get; set; }
        public Result Result { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string response = "{\"S\":\"Success\",\"Result\":{\"Data\":[[2251,2570205,\"05 - Sep - 19 09:53 AM\",\"--\",\"Rs. 0\",\"Cash\",\"Amount Paid : 0\"],[2248,3817456,\"01 - Sep - 19 08:53 AM\",\"--\",\"Rs. 168.00\",\"NC\",\"Reason: NC\"],[2247,2997168,\"01 - Sep - 19 08:49 AM\",\"16\",\"Rs. 660.00\",\"Card\",\"Amount Paid : 660, Type: Visa\"],[2245,6410400,\"01 - Sep - 19 08:46 AM\",\"16\",\"Rs. 726.00\",\"Card\",\"Amount Paid : 726, Type: Visa\"]],\"Headers\":[\"S.No.\",\"Order Id\",\"Date\",\"Table No\",\"Amount\",\"Mode of Payment\",\"More Info\"],\"Footer\":[\"Total\",\"4\",\"\",\"\",\"Rs. 1,386.00\",\"\",\"\"]}}";
        ReportRootObject jsonResult = new ReportRootObject();
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, jsonResult);

        Console.WriteLine($"SerialNumber: {jsonResult.Result.Data[0][0]}");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @krishna-mohan-varma